# Calling a function and taking one return out of multiple ones

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, declaration

I'm having a function which computes some averages of some values as inputs and the outputs are two ways of computing average: normal average and logarithmic mean.

```
void average_function(double nb1, double nb2, double &avr1, double &avr2)
{
....
}
```

in the main program: I just want to call just the first return, I mean, avr1, and I don't want to have the output avr2. I think if it's a pointer, you shall put to avr2=NULL but not in that case.

```
double avr1;
average_function(nb1, nb2, avr1, avr2)
```

Is there a way to output just avr1 in that situation? Or, I shall seperate the different average functions to two ones: one to return avr1 and the other to return avr2 (something that I really don't want to do).

Comment: Provide two functions, one for each average type. That will lead to less confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate these into 2 functions. And you should return results to the caller with (shockingly?) a return value...

```
double Average(double nb1, double nb2);
double LogarithmicMean(double nb1, double nb2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely break it up in two functions, and have the average as the return parameter of those functions, such as:

```
double normalAverage(double nb1, double nb2);
double logarithmicMean(double nb1, double nb2);

...

double normalAvg = normalAverage(15.25, 99.12);
double logMean = logarithmicMean(15.25, 99.12);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are solutions, none of which is particularly beatuiful (in fact I find both questionable).  But for educational purposes:

You can make a functionally overloaded function that discards the 2nd parameter

```
void average_function(double nb1, double nb2, double &avr1, double &avr2)
{
  ....
}

void average_function(double nb1, double nb2, double &avr1)
{
     double dummy;
     average_function(nb1, nb2, avr1, dummy);

}
```

Further, if you define a global double value somewhere, you could use it as a default parameter:

```
static double dummy;

void average_function(double nb1, double nb2, double &avr1, double &avr2= dummy)
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the argument as pointer, and not computing the corresponding mean if it is `nullptr` is quite common and absolutely ok.

Design-wise, you should probably split the functionality into two functions, though. My response is based on your saying that you don't want to do this. The only reason you could have for keeping it in one function is if the amount of data to be processed is so large that it blows away the CPU caches, and it therefore would be desirable to only traverse once.

Comment: Ya, that's 'absolutely ok' if this were 1999. In the world where you never knew: Can I pass NULL? Why am I passing a pointer, are they going to read it? store it? write to it? That world is gone. Thankfully. Crappy API.

Comment: If it is const, they are only going to read, if it is not it ought to be documented. This argument applies to references as well. Passing pointers to indicate optional arguments is not bad API design per se, the only thing that is bad is using pointers where references would do the job as well. If an API is consistent in that regard, a pointer parameter is always to be interpreted as "could be null". While I appreciate your rant, it does not help with how things are.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` operator, when used in a function declaration, is the reference operator. It means that any parameters passed into your function are passed *by reference*, which means any changes made by the function to the value are kept after the function is concluded. (parameters passed into your function the normal way, *by value*, are effectively copied into the function; any changes the function makes will not apply to the outside value). A reference is not quite a pointer, which is why you can't pass it NULL.

The best choice is to separate the functions. It's best to make each function be supposed to do one "thing", and if there is a distinct thing to do, do it differently.

If you'd still like to use only one function, you can pass an invalid value to `&avr2` (such as 0, if that is in fact invalid), and within the function whether it is 0 or not; if it is, perform the function operation that does not involve using `&avr2`. If it isn't 0, use `&avr2`.

```
void average_function(double nb1, double nb2, double &avr1, double &avr2)
{
    if(avr2==0)
    {
        //non-avr2 option
    } else {
        //avr2 option
    }
}
```